# How do I create an "impersonation" module in terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to write clean terraform configurations with separation of roles using the following project structure :

```
 terraform-infra-genesis
 ┣ modules
 ┃ ┗ impersonation
 ┃ ┃ ┣ generic_sa_impersonation.tf
 ┃ ┃ ┣ inputs.tf
 ┃ ┃ ┗ test_i1.tfvars
 ┣ org
 ┃ ┣ main.tf
 ┃ ┣ outputs.tf
 ┃ ┣ terraform.tfvars
 ┃ ┗ variables.tf
 ┣ .gitignore
 ┗ README.md
```

My goal (for now) is to run via the `org` directory the definition of my infrastructure.

First step - **without using modules** : I was able to create said infrastructure by using `Service account impersonation` [guide found here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/terraform-assume-role-and-service-account-impersonation-on-google-cloud-ffc553863e72). Upon performing `terraform apply`, my infrastructure state on **GCP** is updated. No problems here.

Second step - I create the **modules/impersionation** that I will use, as it could be useful for several other instances, such as creating a VPC, Subnets, etc... The goal here is that this module will generate an access token for a set number of seconds. So no outputs are expected

In my **modules/impersonation** I write the following code :

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "3.85.0"
    }
  }
}

# For a list of all scopes visit : https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes
provider "google" {
  alias  = "service_account_impersonation"
  scopes = var.p_info.scopes
}

data "google_service_account_access_token" "service_account_to_impersonate" {
  provider               = google.service_account_impersonation
  target_service_account = var.sa_to_impersonate_info.email
  scopes                 = var.sa_to_impersonate_info.token_scopes
  lifetime               = var.sa_to_impersonate_info.token_lifetime
}

provider "google" {
  access_token = data.google_service_account_access_token.service_account_to_impersonate.access_token
  region       = var.p_info.region
  zone         = var.p_info.zone
}

# Add users as a token creators and impersonators for this service account
resource "google_service_account_iam_binding" "impersonators" {
  for_each = toset([
    for user in var.user_accs_impersonators_info : "${user.acc_type}:${user.acc_details.email}"
  ])
  service_account_id = "projects/${var.sa_to_impersonate_info.belonging_project_id}/serviceAccounts/${var.sa_to_impersonate_info.email}"
  role               = "roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator"
  members            = [each.key]
}
```

I test/debug this module by creating **test_i1.tfvars** that will contain the following (redacted) values :

```
p_info = {
  scopes = [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
  ]
  region = <redacted>
  zone   = <redacted>
}

sa_to_impersonate_info = {
  email                = <redacted>
  belonging_org_id     = <redacted>
  belonging_project_id = <redacted>
  token_lifetime       = "1200s"
  token_scopes         = ["cloud-platform", "userinfo-email"]
}


user_accs_impersonators_info = [{
  acc_type = "user",
  acc_details = {
    email = <redacted>
  },
}]
```

It works when I perform a `terraform plan`, the following output is displayed:

```
Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

    Terraform will perform the following actions:
    ... <redacted> ...
    Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

Third step - I use the previously written module in the `org/main.tf`:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "3.85.0"
    }
  }
}

module "terraform_super_admin_service_account_impersonation" {
  source = "../modules/impersonation"
  p_info = {
    region = <redacted>
    zone   = <redacted>
    scopes = [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    ]
  }
  sa_to_impersonate_info = {
    email                = <redacted>
    belonging_org_id     = <redacted>
    belonging_project_id = <redacted>
    token_lifetime       = "1200s"
    token_scopes = [
      "cloud-platform", "userinfo-email"
    ]
  }

  user_accs_impersonators_info = [{
    acc_type = "user"
    acc_details = {
      email = <redacted>
    }
  }]
}
```

Here I get the error :

```
Error: Error when reading or editing Resource "service account '<redacted>'" with IAM Binding (Role "roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator"): Error retrieving IAM policy for service account '<redacted>': googleapi: Error 403: Permission iam.serviceAccounts.getIamPolicy is required to perform this operation on service account '<redacted>'., forbidden
```

But this doesn't make sense since I just used these same credentials in step1 & step2... I'm thinking maybe I'm using the **provider** block wrong in the module, but I don't see that I have a choice in order to make the impersonation happen.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provider block in your "impersonation" module is ignored when  you are using that module from your top-level Terraform code. As per [the documentation](https://www.terraform.io/language/modules/develop/providers):

> Provider configurations, unlike most other concepts in Terraform, are global to an entire Terraform configuration and can be shared across module boundaries. Provider configurations can be defined only in a root Terraform module.

and:

> A module intended to be called by one or more other modules must not contain any provider blocks.

So your `provider` configuration in your module was only working when you were running `terraform` commands from within the same folder. Once you started running `terraform` commands at your top level folder that configuration was ignored.

In my experience what you are trying to do in the "impersonation" module simply belongs in a top-level .tf file, instead of in a module.

Comment: Thank you @MarkB, so in order to impersonate several different service accounts, such as networking-admin, infra-admin, etc... what would you recommend? A copy-paste of said code would be an anti-pattern...

Comment: If you really want to do your terraform permissions that way, I don't think you have any other choice than to copy/paste, since the `provider` block can't have a `count` or `for_each`.